# fundamental question: creating a transaction

Tags: monerod, linux

I want to learn more about the monero daemon. If i submit a used hash, this should return a rejected hash. I would like to learn it by doing it.
what are the JSON fields sent in a request in order  to connect to the network, create a transaction, and submit a hash?

Comment: The best way in my opinion would be to become member of any GitHub.com
project focused on XMR (monero) daemon development.
Choose project in preferred programming language and yours knowledge will be significantly improved.